# Executing a script in a different directory without having to use the full path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I generate a bash script named "script1" and place it in the directory /home/Me/bin. I want to execute it (just by calling it's name ./script1) without the complete path from any directory. How can I do it? Is there any specific command?

Comment: First you need to know the meaning of `./` this is the path of the script, where `./` means current directory. So , one thing you can do is to add `/home/Me/bin` in `$PATH` and then call your script from any location by doing `script1`

Answer (score 0):

The directory the script is in needs to be included in your `PATH` environment variable. `$HOME/bin` usually is included already. Otherwise, you can add it in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/Me/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `"/home/Me/bin"` to your `PATH`.

Then, you can just call `"script1"`.